# Is it possible to deliver a grails plugin to a customer without source

Tags: grails, plugins

He must be able to use all features of the plugin, without accessing to source. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean a [binary plugin](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/plugins.html#binaryPlugins)

These are possible since Grails 2